# How can I get the color that is at a set of coordinates in python turtle?

Tags: python, python-turtle

With python, I'm trying to make a function that gets the colour that the turtle is currently on top of. I've found that turtle.pos() gives me coordinates of its location, how can I use those coordinates to get colours?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this would be using the steps shown here: https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-find-the-rgb-value-of-a-pixel-in-python

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this is to append every turtle you create into a list, then in your main game loop, loop through the list of turtle to see if the `turtle.distance()` is smaller than a certain value:

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
turtles = []

yertle = turtle.Turtle('turtle')

while True:
    wn.tracer(0)
    for t in turtles:
        if yertle.distance(t) < 20 and yertle != t:
            print(f'Touched {t.color()}')
    wn.update()
```

In the above code I used `if yertle.distance(t) < 20` which is for when all the turtles are the default size: `20`.